# How to index data by using pivot_table in pandas?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I just started studying pandas.
And now I am practicing using pivot_table in pandas and I have a question how to index the data.
The attached picture shows what I want to do.
How can I get the result by using pivot_table?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7T8F.png)

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplier here is aggregate `sum` and transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Status').sum().T
print (df1)
```

If need pivoting then use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = (df.melt('Status')
         .pivot_table(index='variable',
                      columns='Status',
                      values='value', 
                      aggfunc='sum'))
print (df1)
```